# How do I prove that this recurrence relation is O(n^2)

Tags: analysis, algorithms, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

I need to prove that $T(n)$ is $O(n^2)$:
$$T(1)=a$$ 
$$T(n)=T(n-1)+\log(n-1)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just expand the equation:
$$T(n) = \log(n-1) + \log(n-2) + \cdots + \log(1) = \log((n-1)!) < \log(n^n) = n\log(n)=O(n^2)$$